# How to transpile a single node package when using @babel/register in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, openlayers, babeljs

I'm running a node server for SSR purposes. To be able to import my (ES6+) React components I `require('@babel/register')` at the top of my file, however, some of these components have dependencies on a `node_modules` package (OpenLayers) that is in ES6 and isn't transpiled by Babel.

I tried adding an `{ ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!ol)/] }` but then I start getting errors on somewhere else apparently related to babel:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
at Converter.toBase64 (<MY_PROJECT>\node_modules\convert-source-map\index.js:61:28)
at Converter.toComment (<MY_PROJECT>\node_modules\convert-source-map\index.js:65:21)
...
```

EDIT: another option would be to mock this module altogether, since I don't really need the functionality in SSR land.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I procced without using register:

1. Package installation (dev)

   npm install @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env --save-dev
2. Create .babelrc file in the project root, and fill it with this:

   {
        "presets": [
           "@babel/preset-env"
        ]
   }
3. Then in package json file (scripts object), you can add this:

   "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./bin/www",

That is because I use nodemon package, and my main file is www (expressjs generator).
And you can run :

```
npm start dev
```